# Camera sensor plugin publishing old frames

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems that `gazebo_ros_camera.so` publishes camera frames with a lag of one update period, ie. a camera frame goes into ROS topic at the time the next frame is grabbed.

Our robot uses 3fps camera, which is fine in the real robot, but the simulations are not very useful, if the frames are > 1/3 s delayed.

Is there a fix for this issue?

The setup is ROS Groovy / Gazebo 1.2.5.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2521/camera-sensor-plugin-publishing-old-frames/) by [r0nald](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/138/r0nald/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would try Gazebo 1.7.0. The sensor framework has been broken out into threads from Gazebo 1.5 onward.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1